# sshpass alternative in linux shell/bash code

Tags: ssh, password, sshpass

These are standard `sshpass` commands to read password from file or as argument.

```
user@linux:~$ sshpass -f pwd.txt ssh admin@server
admin@server:~$

user@linux:~$ sshpass -p P@55 ssh admin@server
admin@server:~$
```

Is it possible to write the same program/script in shell if `expect` not available?

`Public/private` key is not the option in this case.

If there's available code to provide the same functionality as `sshpass` out there, please let me know.

The simplest the code, the better.

Comment: Please have a look at my script(1) kludge [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1005485/487680). You may have to adjust the timeout. YMMV.

Comment: @mosvy, yeah it works, I changed it to `sleep 10`. I wish there is a solution without depending on `sleep` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `script(1)` as a mini-expect, provided that you can cope with adjusting arbitrary timeouts, which is of course quite kludgy:

```
{ sleep 1; echo PASSWD; } | script -q /dev/null -c 'ssh user@host CMD'
```

or with the syntax of BSD's `script(1)`:

```
{ sleep 1; echo PASSWD; } | script -q /dev/null ssh user@host CMD
```

The `sleep` is necessary because `ssh` will drain the tty's input buffer (and discard whatever was already written to it) before reading the password. If the remote server is *sometimes* slow to respond, using a "large-enough" timeout may be unpractical.

`sshpass`, `expect` etc handle that by waiting to `ssh` to write the `... password:` prompt before they write the password to the master end of the pty. Doing that from a standard shell is neither simple nor very robust. Here is a kludge using a named pipe:

```
passwdcmd(){
    t=$(mktemp -u); mkfifo "$t" || return
    script /dev/null -qc "$2" <>"$t" | { dd count=1 2>/dev/null; echo "$1" >"$t"; rm "$t"; cat; }
}

passwdcmd PASSWD 'ssh user@host CMD'
```

Of course, this is not very secure, especially since `echo` may not be a/the shell built-in. For any non-interactive use of ssh, **use public key authentication**.

Answer (score 1):

Just found amazing bash script which implements sshpass on pure bash:

- https://github.com/huan/sshpass.sh